# Internet communication between programs, without worry in C#?

Tags: c#

I want to provide a direct connection between two instances of my program, which are located on two different computers.
I already have the means to obtain the IP addresses, but how do I make a connection between my programs and have no trouble with the firewall or ports?
I need to send serialized objects through the connection.

**Edit2**: The specific term is **peer-to-peer** connection.

**Edit: I see I need to explain the "no trouble" part.**

First, when a program attempts to communicate to the internet, the annoying Windows Firewall permission dialog opens.
On Windows 7, you have two checkboxes:
1. Allow on private (home/work) networks, which is checked by default and, sometimes, cannot be unchecked.
2. Allow on public networks, which is either checked or unchecked by default...

**NO ONE** I know makes sure that all the check boxes are checked. **NO ONE**.
This can interrupt the program sometimes in bad ways, without people knowing!

Next... Most people are behind a router and routers usually block all the requests to undefined ports, unless the rules are changed.
Nobody will accept to add these rules just to use a program. **Nobody**.

Comment: You cannot be sure to have "no" trouble with the firewall or ports because those are a part of the underlying technology that your communication protocols sit on top of.  That's rather like saying, what kind of car should I drive from New York to Chicago and be guaranteed you'll have no tolls and hit no road construction...

Comment: Please be more specific with your needs. Generally WCF will be good for you in most cases.

Comment: Before anyone can give you a more specific answer than "use WCF" you need to give us information about the network architecture you are tackling.  What's the "firewall" is it just Windows Firewall? Or a corporate network? Or something in between?

Comment: Well, I want a peer-to-peer connection... To send a serialized object. It's all I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, using a `TcpClient` and a `TcpListener` works... as long as I forward the ports on the listener's router.
So this is not an option.

I ended up using my database to queue commands and check for them every once in a while, and dequeue them when necessary.

For the moment, I cannot find any good answer.

Comment: WCF is the way to go. I really wouldn't advise you to try to reinvent the wheel; WCF has support for peer-to-peer built in and will handle de/serialisation of your types etc. and lots more for free.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for this purpose.

It doesn't solve 'all' network problems though, but I doubt any technology would.

Comment: Doesn't this require a server?

Comment: @Vercas: In the sense that one end must host the service and the other must connect to it, yes. But you don't need a physical server or a machine set up to act as one; you just use a 'self-hosting' WCF service.

Comment: This will take some time to test... :(

Comment: @Vercas everything takes time to test if you want to do it well. The upside of using WCF compared to "rolling your own WCFish thing" is that there's a lot less to test

Answer (score 0):

It kind of sounds like you're looking for a way to bypass firewalls so that your users won't have to deal with that kind of stuff while using your program.

If that's indeed the case, think about it this way. Would the Windows Firewall be good at its job if it allowed you (or anyone else) to do that?

What you might want to do is open up a port using TCP and send serialized objects over it to a target listener, which knows how to decode those bits back to objects.

If you need that port open, your users will have to allow that. If they're running a firewall that blocks it, then that firewall needs to be properly configured to allow your program to interact with the target computer.

You can use TcpClient, TcpListener (System.Net) and BinaryFormatter (System.Runtime.Serialization) to send serialized objects over TCP.
Remember you need to specify your custom classes as [Serializable].

Comment: Using `BinaryFormatter` for data sent over plain TCP sounds like a really bad idea. You need to absolutely trust the source of your data if you want to deserialize it using `BinaryFormatter`

Comment: I wouldn't jump ahead and say it's an overall bad idea. After all, if you're transferring plain non-classified data then encrypting it would just be an unnecessary overhead. If you're transferring credit-card information or credentials, then obviously there's much more to know and address rather than simply 'not using BinaryFormatter'.

Comment: Vercas, if you can't get a working connection and your code seems right (have a look at examples from MSDN), then the problem is probably not your code, but the firewall or even lack of network (or whatever). You need to go and have a look in those places.

Comment: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond MY.OWN.SECRET.IP:4444"...

Comment: Would you mind posting the code for both the client and the listener?

Comment: I use the library from this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsByBobJanova.aspx and the same code...

Comment: Like I said in my answer, try using TcpClient and TcpListener directly. If that doesn't work, we'll be able to get a better clue of the reason.